# Android float button over scroll view

Tags: android-layout

I have to put a button at a fix position(top-right) so that when I scroll the screen/view, the button is always visible. It's like a button floating over the view. The button is visible over the scroll view all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a dummy app and it works
here is the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
                <RatingBar android:id="@+id/ratingBar1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RatingBar>
                <Spinner android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/spinner1" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Spinner>
                <Spinner android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/spinner2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"></Spinner>
                <SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekBar1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent"></SeekBar>
                <QuickContactBadge android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/quickContactBadge1" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></QuickContactBadge>
                <RatingBar android:id="@+id/ratingBar2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RatingBar>
                <RadioGroup android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/radioGroup1" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <RadioButton android:text="RadioButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/radio0" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:checked="true"></RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton android:text="RadioButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/radio1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton android:text="RadioButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/radio2" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RadioButton>
                </RadioGroup>
                <Spinner android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/spinner3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"></Spinner>
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="TextView" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>
                <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Button" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/button2"></Button>
                <ProgressBar android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/progressBar1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"></ProgressBar>
                <RatingBar android:id="@+id/ratingBar3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RatingBar>
                <QuickContactBadge android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/quickContactBadge2" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></QuickContactBadge>
                <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Button" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/button3"></Button>
                <CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" android:id="@+id/checkBox1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"></CheckBox>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button1"></Button>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have a relative layout. Inside the layout you will have a scrollview to fill the parent both in height and with and the button will be also inside the layout but it will have align with parent top to true...

this is the answer, if you have any questions ask again

Comment: Hi Lukap, thanks for the reply. The button actually floats over the scroll view i.e. it kind of overlap the view at top position. If I go as per what you said, the scroll will happen below the button and I want the button to be visible all the time over the scrollview.

Comment: well you didn't done exactly what I said to do :),put both the button and the scrollview inside the relative layout, define  align with parent top to true for the button and fill parent for the scrollview

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using xml files to define your layout. Then you need to define the button outside the ScrollView definition, for example:

```
<ScrollView
    ...>

    ...
</ScrollView>

<Button
   ...>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys I know this is a old post just FYI, Google has come up with a library to support the a lot of cool stuff like float button, etc. Worth a look.
[Google Design Support Lib](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)